# How to apply a function row-wise having if-else condition using data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I need to apply a function on a data frame below. 'day' is sales values. I need to shift the sales to right based on offset value. For example in row 1 offset is 1, I need to shift sales by 1 day, if 0 then no shift and henceforth.

```
id <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')  
offset <- c(1,2,3,0,0,2)
day1 <-   c(1,2,3,4,5, 0)
day2 <-   c(1,2,3,4,5, 2)
day3 <-   c(1,2,3,4,5, 6)
day4 <-   c(1,2,3,4,5, 6)
day5 <-   c(1,2,0,4,5, 0)
day6 <-   c(1,0,0,0,5, 0)
day7 <-   c(0,0,0,0,0, 0)
df <- data.frame(id, offset, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7) 

> df
id offset day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
a      1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
b      2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0
c      3    3    3    3    3    0    0    0
d      0    4    4    4    4    4    0    0
e      0    5    5    5    5    5    5    0
f      2    0    2    6    6    0    0    0
```

The result should be like below:

```
> result
id offset day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
a      1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
b      2    0    0    2    2    2    2    2
c      3    0    0    0    3    3    3    3
d      0    4    4    4    4    4    0    0
e      0    5    5    5    5    5    5    0
f      2    0    0    0    2    6    6    0
```

I intended to use following pseudo function row-wise in data.table:

```
shiftSales = function(df){
 if (start > 0) 
 { 
  then_no_shift 
 }
 else
 { 
  offset_by_offset_value
 }
   return(shift_df)  
}
result <- df(,shiftSales(df), by = "id")
```

Note: if it is possible without data.table, I am ok. But my data is large so I thought data.table approach would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to *shift data row-wise across columns* by an offset which is specific for each row. (Unfortunately, the title mentioning *if-else* is somewhat misleading).

All solutions posted so far, are using the `t()` function (matrix transpose) which indicates that the way the data are stored is not particularly well suited for this type of operation.

The solution below uses `melt()` to reshape the data from wide to long form *before* applying a `shift()` operation on *columns*:

```
library(data.table)
# reshape from wide to long
melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns("^day"))[
  # shift values for each id by its individual offset
  , value := shift(value, offset, fill = 0), by = id][
    # reshape to wide format agian for comparison
    , dcast(.SD, id + offset ~ variable)]
```

> ```
>    id offset day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
> 1:  a      1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
> 2:  b      2    0    0    2    2    2    2    2
> 3:  c      3    0    0    0    3    3    3    3
> 4:  d      0    4    4    4    4    4    0    0
> 5:  e      0    5    5    5    5    5    5    0
> 6:  f      2    0    0    0    2    6    6    0
> ```

**Caveat:** It is assumed that `id` is unique. Otherwise, an additional row number needs to be introduced.

---

As already mentioned, I suggest to reconsider the way the data is stored.

Currently, longitudinal data, i.e., `day1`, `day2`, `day3`, ...,  are stored in a data.frame in wide format, i.e., in separate columns. This is not ideal as it requires row-wise operations to be performed across columns.

Instead, the data could be stored as a matrix (with `id` as row names and `offset` stored in a separate vector). Or, if there are other, undisclosed columns, in a data.frame in long format.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for complicated `if/else`. Try the following.

```
df <- data.frame(id, offset, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7)

df[-(1:2)] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) c(rep(0, x[1]), x[2:8])[1:7]))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
# read df
df = read.table(
  header = TRUE,
  text = 
    "
    id offset day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
    a      1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
    b      2    2    2    2    2    2    0    0
    c      3    3    3    3    3    0    0    0
    d      0    4    4    4    4    4    0    0
    e      0    5    5    5    5    5    5    0
    f      2    0    2    6    6    0    0    0
    "
);

# load binhf (for shift function)
library(binhf);

# convert to data table
dt = setDT(df)[
  ,
  # establish the new columns using mapply
  c("day_1", "day_2", "day_3", "day_4", "day_5", "day_6", "day_7") :=
    data.table(
      t(
        x = mapply(
          FUN = function(offset, day_1, day_2, day_3, day_4, day_5, day_6, day_7){
            # make a vector of day_1, day_2, day_3,...,day_7
            vec = c(day_1, day_2, day_3, day_4, day_5, day_6, day_7);

            # shift to the right
            vec_s = shift(v = vec, places = offset, dir = "right");

            # return vec_s
            vec_s;
          },
          # parse vectors
          day_1 = day_1,
          day_2 = day_2,
          day_3 = day_3,
          day_4 = day_4,
          day_5 = day_5,
          day_6 = day_6,
          day_7 = day_7,
          offset = offset
        )
      )
    )
  ][
  # remove unwanted (unshifted) columns
    ,
    -(2:9),
    with = FALSE
  ];

# print dt
dt;

   id day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5 day_6 day_7
1:  a     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
2:  b     0     0     2     2     2     2     2
3:  c     0     0     0     3     3     3     3
4:  d     4     4     4     4     4     0     0
5:  e     5     5     5     5     5     5     0
6:  f     0     0     0     2     6     6     0
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The `data.table` package has its own  `shift()` function. So, I wonder what the reason is to load another package.

Comment: This was because I didn't think data.table had row shift functionality. The better idea as in your answer is to reshape the data first and then use the built in `shift`.

Comment: `data.table`'s `shift()` function has a unique feature: The offset parameter takes vectors. This allows us to create multiple shifted times series in one step. (Not required here, but I have used it already).